# Is there a way to print SVM margin obtained for each kernel used in sklearn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

It is suggested in SVM to experiment with different classifiers using the various kernels available.Tuning the parameters is advised too.I am experimenting with various gamma and regularization parameters. Is there a way to print 'margin' for each experiment?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-separating-hyperplane-py) example on the `sklearn` site.